# Sequence of sums with sign function

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_n\}$ be a bounded sequence of positive numbers, $x_n\in [a,b]$ $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$, $0<a<b$.

How to research the sequence
$$
y_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (x_{k+1}-x_k)\mathrm{sign}\big(\frac{x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k}{k}-x_k\big)?
$$
I reduced it to the form
$$
y_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n} (x_{k+1}-x_k)\mathrm{sign}((x_1-x_k)+(x_2-x_k)+\ldots+(x_{k-1}-x_k)).
$$
The first term of the sum is zero, so one can write $\sum_{k=2}^{n}$.

What are the sufficient conditions on the sequence $\{x_n\}$ for the following statements to be true?

i)
$$
\exists N: \quad \forall n\geq N \quad y_n>0;
$$
ii)
$$
\forall n\in\mathbb{N} \quad \exists m>n: \quad y_m>y_n.
$$

Is it possible to reduce the sum in the right hand for $\{y_n\}$ to the integral?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Where does this come from ? Is it homework ? More context please.